# thread sleep executes directly when I open the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to do make some proccess in the web page and then I want the page sleep like 30 second.

for example

```
public ActionResult Generate()
{
    var formsIdentity = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.User.Identity;
    var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(formsIdentity.Ticket.Name);
    Customer customer = _customerService.Get(x => x.Email == ticket.Name).FirstOrDefault();

    if (model.OldPassword == customer.Password)
    {
        customer.Password = model.NewPassword;
        _customerService.Update(customer, customer.Id);
        return view();
    }
    Thread.Sleep(30000);
    customer.Password = "something";
    _customerService.Update(customer, customer.Id);
    return view();
}
```

In here for example I want to change password via user input. After password change I want the page sleep 30 second and then update the data in database again. But if use thread.sleep page and I try to open the page it doesnt open for 30 second and then it opens so how can I fix it? Changing password is just an example.

Comment: The use of `Thread.Sleep` is a solution, not a requirement. I think the requirement is "prevent the user from attempting another signon for 30 seconds." In a web application, you would do that with a persistent server-side data field representing the lockout expiry, and a check in your controller to ensure it has expired. Executing a `Thread.Sleep` in the controller is bizarre and will have no effect on the end user's browser, except to make your web site seem nonresponsive. A hacker can bypass this by using more than one HTTP client.

Comment: I think you should do this on front-end because the page open is not control by back-end

Answer (score 1):

You should not perform such operations in controller actions you need to use some kind of background processing. Since it seems that you are using .NET Framework so the app possibly hosted inside IIS (which can recycle app pool) then you should look into libraries for standalone background processing like [Hangfire](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire) or [Quartz.NET](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet).